# when i press back arrow in toolbar getting a null object reference

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am trying to my send data from second activity to third activity it working 
fine when I click back arrow in tool back I am getting this error please any one help me how to resolve this one

here my second activity code

```
pos=Integer.parseInt((getIntent().getExtras()).getString("pos"));


    webviewurl=NewsMainFregmant_List.listData.get(pos).getNewsSourceUrl();

    webviewurl2=NewsMainFregmant_List.listData.get(pos).getNewsSourceUrl2();

news_site_link_one=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.news_SourceLink_text_one_t_webview);
news_site_like_two=   (TextView)findViewById(R.id.news_SourceLink_text_two_t_webview);

  news_site_link_one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent webviewintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), News_WebView.class);
       webviewintent.putExtra("webviewurl", webviewurl);
         startActivity(webviewintent);

    }
   });
```

here below my webview

```
 String SourceURL;
WebView webview;
final Activity activity = this;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);




    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news__web_view);
    Intent intent =getIntent();


        SourceURL =  intent.getStringExtra("webviewurl");
    webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);




    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            activity.setTitle("Loading...");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    });

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    webview.loadUrl(SourceURL);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.transition.slide_in_down, R.transition.slide_out_down);

    }
}
```

Here below my error code

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Which line in your code does this error refer to?

Comment: pos=Integer.parseInt((getIntent().getExtras()).getString("pos"));@AHoneyBustard

Comment: Do you know what a Null Pointer exceptions is?

Comment: actualy code was working and getting result when i click back arrorw in tool this error@AHoneyBustard

Comment: What do you mean 'in tool' ?

Comment: toolbar@AHoneyBustard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106255/discussion-between-chanti-and-a-honey-bustard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that this line :

```
pos=Integer.parseInt((getIntent().getExtras()).getString("pos"));
```

points to nothing, getString("pos") does not exist.

There can be many reasons for that. Probably your not filling the intent with Extras when you press back in your Toolbar.

You can do a null check :

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null)
   pos=Integer.parseInt((getIntent().getExtras()).getString("pos"));
```

But better take care of it in your Toolbar back ClickListener and make sure it is not null.

By the way :

```
Integer.parseInt((getIntent().getExtras()).getString("pos"))
```

is not good practice. If you want to get a single Integer from an intent you use :

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("pos", 0); // will be 0 if null
```

You put it in the intent extra like this :

```
intent.putExtra("pos", 666);
```

Now your intent Extra "pos" is assigned the value 666.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like error is in below line
  
 
                pos=Integer.parseInt((getIntent().getExtras()).getString("pos"));

So you can do 2 things here.

**Method1**

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null)
          pos=Integer.parseInt((getIntent().getExtras()).getString("pos"));
```

or

**Method2** 
Change your back pressed method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
  if (webview.canGoBack())
  {
     webview.goBack();
  } else {
          Intent backIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  PreviousClass.class);       
     backIntent.putExtra("pos",pos);
     startActivity(webviewintent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.transition.slide_in_down,  R.transition.slide_out_down);
   }
}
```

but for this u need to pass pos variable on moving from second activity to third also.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Android reference guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()), getExtras():

> returns the map of all extras previously added with putExtra(), **or null if none have been added**.

So it looks like you never called putExtra() or didn't use it correctly.